# ScrollPane in the JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, null-layout-manager

This is part of GUI project I'm working with and I'm trying to make `JScrollPane` to appear in the `JTextArea` when the text is longer than the size of the `JTextArea`. It looks fine to me but the `JScrollPane` still doesn't show up.

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setBounds(77, 27, 561, 146);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 100));
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JPanel panel= new JPanel()
    panel.add(textArea);
```

Can anyone verify this peace of code?

Comment: Make sure you're not adding the text area to any other component also.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `JScrollPane` isn't showing up is because you haven't added it to your GUI...

```
 panel.add(textArea);
```

should be

```
 panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Why one might ask? 
Because in this line:
`JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);` we see that the `JScrollPane's` constructor takes in the `JTextArea/etc` thus removing any need to add the `textArea` to the GUI because the `textArea` is now part of the `scrollPane` which, in turn, should be added to the GUI.

Comment: @user2999915 Well I can 100% assure you that the JScrollPane is part of the panel, the rest is up to you buddy.

Comment: That's right! It is part of the panel! Sorry for confusing you :)

Comment: @user2999915 The snippet of code you've provided looks fine to me so I'd start looking for the bug in different parts of the program.